# How to iterate over a QVariantList of QVariants and modify it

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QVariant that is a QVariantList of QVariantMaps.

I need to iterate over the list and replace or update some of the maps.  I can iterate over them using a `QVariantList::Iterator` like this:

```
        for (QVariantList::iterator j = monkey.value("sublist").toList().begin(); j != monkey.value("sublist").toList().end(); j++)
        {
            cDebug() << j->toMap().value("element");
        }
```

However, that doesn't let me modify what j is pointing to.  I tried to use a mutable iterator but I couldn't get it to work with all these nested QVariants.

I am sure I am missing some obvious way to achieve this but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I do not think that you are missing anything obvious. Editing a nested structure of `QVariant`s is not simple. You must realize that each of functions `value()`, `toMap()` or `toList()` create a copy of the data. They do not return a reference so you cannot edit them directly because changing the copied data will not change the original data.

Comment: Your loop exhibits undefined behavior. `QVariant::toList()` returns a copy of the list it stores, by value. The iterator obtained by `toList().begin()` points into a different container than the one returned by `toList().end()`

Comment: So I guess if I need to modify elements of that data structure I need to recursively copy it and modify it as I go?